# Convert CURL request to RestClient request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, rest-client

I have a curl request to fetch data from elasticsearch

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_all/_search?search_type=count&q=_type:invoice" -d '
    {
    "aggs" :
        {
            "by_index" :
                {"terms" : {"field" : "_index"}},
            "aggs" :
                {"by_state" : {"terms" : {"field" : "state"}}}
        }
}'
```

I works fine from terminal, now in application i was to use this request.

I am using [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) to send a GET request:

```
RestClient.get curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_all/_search?search_type=count&q=_type:invoice"
```

How can i pass the filters to it like i did in curl request ?

Comment: Take the string that you passed to `-d`, and pass it as the 2nd parameter to `get`. And it's `RestClient.get url, d_string`

Comment: Yes, I tried but getting NoMethodError: undefined method `delete_if' for #<String:0x00000008c96438> error

Comment: RestClient doesn't seem to have a way to send a payload (-d) via GET. https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client You might want to use Net::HTTP directly.